# Ffmpeg libx265 vs hevc_nvenc

Tags: nvidia, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have an Nvidia graphics card, and am using the proprietary drivers.

I looked into the ffmpeg H265 encoders available to me, and found hevc_nvenc. Using hevc_nvenc does in fact use the GPU to encode the video, which massively increases encode time, but the output filesize is considerably larger.

For example: (input.mp4 is H264 and aac)

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -c:a libopus -crf 26 libx265_output.mkv`

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i input.mp4 -c:v hevc_nvenc -c:a libopus -crf 26 hevc_nvenc_output.mkv`

Filesizes are:

```
input.mp4             351M
libx265_output.mkv    134M
hevc_nvenc_output.mkv 360M
```

ffprobe shows both outputs as hevc encoded, and input as h264.

So why does hevc_nvenc seem to perform so poorly? There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: you mean "massively decreases encode time" ?

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

The hardware accelerated encoders do not support Constant Rate Factor (CRF, `-crf`) to determine size/quality ratio. You can check what the encoder supports, e.g. with `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_nvenc -hide_banner`. [Dennis Mungai's detailed answer](https://superuser.com/a/1236387/1203531) to '[How can I use CRF encoding with nvenc in ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/q/1236275/1203531)' at Superuser suggests to use `-cq:v 19` and `-rc:v vbr` parameters instead to get constant quality with variable bitrate. You probably want to consider that to help in your case.

It worth noting that this is still different from CRF because constant quality, as it is determined by `-cq`, sets constant quantization parameter (CQP) instead. Here's a quote from the [CRF Guide by
Werner Robitza](https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html) explaining why CRF still allows to save bits in comparison to setting constant QP:

> … The quantization parameter defines how much information to discard from a given block of pixels (a Macroblock). This typically leads to a hugely varying bitrate over the entire sequence.
>
> Constant Rate Factor is a little more sophisticated than that. It will compress different frames by different amounts, thus varying the QP as necessary to maintain a certain level of perceived quality. It does this by taking motion into account. …

---

**Original answer**

[`ffmpeg` wiki asserts](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) that this is typical for hardware accelerated encoding:

> Hardware encoders typically generate output of significantly lower quality than good software encoders like x264, but are generally faster and do not use much CPU resource. (That is, they require a higher bitrate to make output with the same perceptual quality, or they make output with a lower perceptual quality at the same bitrate.)

Peter Cordes suggested the following explanation as a part of [his answer at Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/14657) to '[Why processor is "better" for encoding than GPU?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/14656)':

> **My understanding** is that the search space for video encoding is SO big that smart heuristics for early-termination of search paths on CPUs beat the brute-force GPUs bring to the table, at least for high quality encoding. It's only compared to `-preset ultrafast` where you might reasonably choose HW encoding over x264, esp. if you have a slow CPU (like laptop with dual core and no hyperthreading). On a fast CPU (i7 quad core with hyperthreading), x264 `superfast` is probably going to be as fast, and look better (at the same bitrate).
>
> If you're making an encode where rate-distortion (quality per file size) matters at all, you should use x264 `-preset medium` or slower. If you're archiving something, spending a bit more CPU time now will save bytes for as long as you're keeping that file around.

Comment: In a nutshell: Hardware accelerated implementations of compressors are designed for speed. Some features cannot be implemented due to architectural limitations. For this reason, when targeting the same quality, hardware compression will likely result in larger file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_nvenc`

gives your actual list of presets

```
  -preset            <int>        E..V....... Set the encoding preset (from 0 to 18) (default p4)
     default         0            E..V.......
     slow            1            E..V....... hq 2 passes
     medium          2            E..V....... hq 1 pass
     fast            3            E..V....... hp 1 pass
     hp              4            E..V.......
     hq              5            E..V.......
     bd              6            E..V.......
     ll              7            E..V....... low latency
     llhq            8            E..V....... low latency hq
     llhp            9            E..V....... low latency hp
     lossless        10           E..V....... lossless
     losslesshp      11           E..V....... lossless hp
     p1              12           E..V....... fastest (lowest quality)
     p2              13           E..V....... faster (lower quality)
     p3              14           E..V....... fast (low quality)
     p4              15           E..V....... medium (default)
     p5              16           E..V....... slow (good quality)
     p6              17           E..V....... slower (better quality)
     p7              18           E..V....... slowest (best quality)
  -tune              <int>        E..V....... Set the encoding tuning info (from 1 to 4) (default hq)
```

Comment: This is probably better as an edit to the other answer as it does not answer the question.